# What if a native class/method only defined in a newer Java version?

Tags: java, version, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

As far as i know, during the compile time of Java, only the class/method signatures are recorded. The actual implementations are binded until the running time, in the JVM.

Let's imagine there is a **native** Java class called `MyClass`. And in Java version 1.6:

```
public class NativeClass {
    public String getVersion() { return "1.6"; }
}
```

And in Java version 1.7:

```
public class NativeClass {
    public String getVersion() { return "1.7"; }
    public String somethingMore() { return "more"; }
}
```

Our IDE and compiler are 1.7. After the program compiled, when we run it in JRE 1.6 and 1.7, we will have different return values from `NativeClass.getVersion();`. This is known.

But what will happen if we run `NativeClass.somethingMore()` on JRE 1.6?

If possible, please give an example in the real Java source, where certain class/method only exist in a newer version.

Comment: Why not just download JRE 1.6 and test it yourself?

Comment: i cant think of an example of that case in my mind. For user defined classes, it behave identical across all the versions.

Comment: Ah, native classes, that changes things.

Comment: What do you mean by "NativeClass"? One that's in the JDK? One that's implemented using the `native` keyword? It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: @JoachimSauer. One that's originally in the API, opposed to a user defined class. Nothing about the `native` keyword. (i dont know how to use that keyword tbh.)

Answer (score 2):

> But what will happen if we run NativeClass.somethingMore() on JRE 1.6?

A [`NoSuchMethodError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html) will be thrown.

> Thrown if an application tries to call a specified method of a class (either static or instance), and that class no longer has a definition of that method.

---

> What if a class that doesn't exist? There is no `NoSuchClassError`

See [`NoClassDefFoundError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) & [`ClassNotFoundException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html).

But don't ask me a) why there are two of them. b) why one is used over the other/what the difference is, or c) why methods also have [`NoSuchMethodException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html).

It seems they should all be an `Error` rather than an `Exception`.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! What if a class that doesn't exist? There is no `NoSuchClassError` :-/

Comment: @AndrewThompson - there are two of them because they are used in different situations and they mean different things.  The first one means that the JVM is in a state where it is unsafe to proceed; e.g. because the application's static dependencies could not be resolved.  The second one happens when `Class.forName()` fails, and there is no technical reason why an application couldn't recover.

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Thomson is correct as far as he goes.  Here's a more fulsome answer:

The first point is that if you compile code using a Java 1.7 SDK (or IDE), and try to run it on Java 1.6 (or earlier), you *may* run into a "magic number" error.  Basically, unless the "target version" is set to the older version, the compiler will emit bytecode files that the older JVM cannot understand.

Once you have gotten past that:

- Attempting to call a method that doesn't exist will result in a `NoSuchMethodError`.
- Attempting to use (in any way) a class that doesn't exist will result in a `ClassDefNotFoundError`.

The errors are detected and thrown at the point when the JVM tries to resolve the dependencies between the classes.  (This is referred as "linking" in the JLS.  It happens some time before the class is "initialized", but the JVM is free to implement loading and linking lazily so it might not happen instantly on application startup.

Both of these are **fatal errors**.  They leave the JVM in a state where the application is unlikely to be able to recover because an indeterminate set of the application's essential classes are not usable.

These are examples of "binary compatibility errors".  Other examples include things like missing fields, methods with the wrong signatures, some changes in access modifiers, changes to the inheritance hierarchy, and so on.  (There is a whole JLS chapter that deals with the binary compatibility rules; i.e. what you can and can't change in a class without breaking compatibility.)

This is all common sense really.  If you attempt to call a method that isn't there or use a class that isn't there, bailing out with a fatal error is the only safe thing to do.  There are practical limits to "write once, run anywhere".

---

If you want a simple example, try running an application that uses [`String.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) on a Java 1.5 or earlier JVM.  (Or an early release Android phone ...)

---

You won't get a `ClassNotFoundException`.  That is only thrown when you attempt to load classes using `Class.forName(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

This code works well with the latest MySQL JDBC driver - mysql-connector-5.1.22

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "root");
conn.getSchema();
```

but if I use an older version, eg mysql-connector-5.1.20 I'll get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.getSchema()Ljava/lang/String;
    at main.MySQL.main(MySQL.java:21)
```

because `Connection.getSchema` is since 1.7.

If a concrete class is missing, eg. Integer.compare(int, int) is since 1.7 you'll get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`

If a JRE class was missing, e.g. java.util.Scanner is since 1.5 and I used JRE 1.4 I would get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`